# How to use a stoi, and return false if the string has a letter in c++?

Tags: c++, string, int

So, I have this code in C++, and need to use stoi to test if the String (a) has a letter, if doesn't have, send the number to int, and if has return false.

**my code**

```
void main(){

  string a = "a1321";
  int b;
  if (stoi(a)){
    b = stoi(a);
    cout << b << endl;
  }
  else cout << "ERROR"<< endl;

  system("pause");

}
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: You need to look up how `stoi`  signals failure: try http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: Do you have to absolutely use stoi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `stoi` returns the integer value if parsed you can't directly use the return value to check for correctness.

You could catch `std::invalid_argument` exception but it could be too much. If you don't mind using `strol` C function instead that `std::stoi` you can do something like

```
bool isNumber(const std::string& str)
{
  char* ptr;
  strtol(str.c_str(), &ptr, 10);
  return *ptr == '\0';
}
```

which exploits the fact that the function sets the second `char**` argument to the first non numerical character in the passed string, which should be '\0' for a string which just contains a number.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but how do I use that "& str" parameter?

Comment: it's a const reference to a string: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Comment: `stoi` has the same second parameter (it's optional)

Answer (score 0):

You could write function like that:

```
bool try_stoi(int & i, const string & s){
    try {
        size_t pos;
        i = stoi(s, &pos);
        return pos == s.size();
    }
    catch (const std::invalid_argument&) {
         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but how do I use that "int & i" and "string & s" parameters?

Comment: The failure condition is too weak -- you need to use the second parameter to detect trailing non-numeric characters.

Comment: For the second check, don’t compare the pointer contents (it may fail when the string contains null characters), compare the pointer position in the string.

Answer (score 0):

//use this code

```
int main() {
  string a;
  
  cin >> a;
  
  try {
    int b;
    b = stoi(a);
    cout << b;
  } 
  catch (exception e) {
    cout << "string not converted";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include an explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer much more useful to future readers.